# Disable BeautifulSoup lxml parser logs

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am working with the BeautifulSoup library to parse multiple HTMLs and I keep getting this annoying error message and can't find a way to stop printing it.

```
document = BeautifulSoup(html_content_bytes, 'lxml')
```

output:

```
encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xC2 0xA0 0x2F 0xC2
encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x80 0x34 0x33 0x30
encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x80 0x34 0x33 0x30
```

I've tried disabling logging and also disabling print statements from that line and still I get those warnings. From what I've read, the error comes from a library lxml uses called libxml2.

I get why I get that error, that's not the problem. I just don't want all those warnings to keep printing.

Comment: Can you try decode the bytes first (for example from `utf-8`)? `BeautifulSoup(html_content_bytes.decode('utf-8'), 'lxml')`

Comment: @AndrejKesely that would force me to do encoding detection beforehand and I already tried with cchardet and UnicodeDammit (the one Beautifulsoup uses) and sometimes I can't get the same results as when I leave it to be handled by BS4 so I would prefer to avoid doing this.